# Django project configuration error

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-admin

I'm new to Django. I understand basic Django MVC architecture.
After little bit googling I found that we should follow below directory structure instead of auto generated using `django-admin.py startproject myproj` and `manage.py startapp app1`.

Now my Django project structure is.(I've skipped few things like logs,fabfile,etc for sake of small question detail)

```
ROOT_DIR
    |-- manage.py
    |-- readme.txt
    |-- requirements.txt
    `-- webapp
        |-- apps
        |   |-- app1
        |   |   |-- admin.py
        |   |   |-- __init__.py
        |   |   |-- models.py
        |   |   |-- tests.py
        |   |   |-- urls.py
        |   |   `-- views.py
        |   |-- app2
        |   |   |-- admin.py
        |   |   |-- __init__.py
        |   |   |-- models.py
        |   |   |-- tests.py
        |   |   |-- urls.py
        |   |   `-- views.py
        |   `-- __init__.py
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- settings
        |   |-- __init__.py
        |   |-- common.py
        |   |-- development.py
        |   `-- production.py
        |-- static #CSS,JS,Images...
        |-- templates
        |-- urls.py
        `-- wsgi.py
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "webapp.settings.development")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**manage.py**

```
import os,sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "webapp.settings.development")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

but when I run `python manage.py runserver`  I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/eric/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/eric/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/eric/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/eric/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/home/eric/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/home/eric/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/home/eric/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/home/eric/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/home/eric/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named app2
```

I have put a check print statement in `development.py` at beginning and end of the file. 
`print INSTALLED_APPS`

and when I runserver it prints all value of this `INSTALLED_APPS` list(I mean all apps I'm getting in development.py. INSTALLED_APPS variable is in common.py and development.py is importing common.py).

I've no clue where am I making mistake. (Is this because I'm using list instead of tuple for installed_apps variable? and I'm using `from common import *` but I dont think that this import statement is the main cause for this error. do I have to import someother things like `from __future__ import ...*`)

PS: if you have any suggestion related to structure then most welcome but I'm more concerned about this error.

**EDIT:**

**common.py**

```
import os
import sys

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "webapp")

sys.path.append(PROJECT_DIR + '/apps')

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'south',
    'app1',
    'app2',
]

...
```

Comment: I would also recommend `python manage.py startapp app_name` to create your apps

Comment: yeah thats alright. I use that as you can see in my question detail

Comment: Can you show the value of INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: yeah its a simple list containing all apps including django and thirdparty apps like south.@DanielRoseman
it's not a tuple, that is the cause?

Comment: @user3810188 I am betting your directory structure (which doesn't seem to be setup by `manage.py`) is throwing manage.py off.

Comment: I didn't ask what type it was, I asked for its value. How are you referring to your apps in it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: sorry. Please check updated question details. `common.py` includes INSTALLED_APPS variable

Comment: Also I can't imagine why "Googling" would tell you to use a different app structure from the one that is created by the project itself. Why would that be true?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `webapp/apps` is not on your path so it does not look there and find the `app2` module.

I find I am always having to modify the `PYTHONPATH` for various reasons... and each project/environment ends up with an `init_pythonpath.py` file:

```
import sys

def init_pythonpath():
    path = '/home/patrick/path/to/project'
    venv = '/home/patrick/.virtualenvs/venv_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
    if venv not in sys.path:
        sys.path.insert(0, venv)
    if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.insert(0, path)
```

Then, in `manage.py` or `wsgi.py` I add this incantation:

```
import imp
init_pythonpath_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'init_pythonpath.py')
init_pythonpath = imp.load_source('init_pythonpath', init_pythonpath_path)
init_pythonpath.init_pythonpath()

import sys

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

# ...
```

It may work for you.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try your solution but please first check edited details(thats what my common.py file looks like)
It's in system path(how do I know at runtime `print PYTHONPATH` not working)